# How do I open a TCP port on an AWS instance?

Tags: amazon-web-services, tcp, firewall

I have a TCP socket server running on port 8002 on an AWS instance. I can connect to it from localhost, via 127.0.0.1 or the internal AWS IP address, but I cannot connect via the public IP address from localhost, from another AWS instance, or from the internet. I cannot connect from another AWS instance whether I use the internal or public IP.

I have opened the port in the active Security Group and there does not seem to be any additional firewall running on the instance (ufw status returns "inactive", and I don't see iptables installed).

The instance is running Ubuntu 14.04LTS, and if it helps the server application is in Node.

The instance also runs nginx on port 80, which is working and allowing traffic from outside.

Comment: Is your instance launched in a public subnet of a VPC where internet gateway is attached?

Comment: Troubleshooting connectivity: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/TroubleshootingInstancesConnecting.html

Comment: Yes, it's on a public subnet (and the web server on port 80 is accessible - I've updated the question to include that)

Comment: @jarmod Thank you for that! I've now gone through that document and everything looks like it should work.

Comment: TCP server only bound to the loopback interface (127.0.0.1) when it should be all interfaces (0.0.0.0)?

Answer (score 1):

You may check for following configurations,

1. Make sure an internet gateway is attached to the VPC
2. Check if the subnet that the instance is launched pointed to the internet gateway
3. Check if the instance has a public IP/Elastic IP assigned
4. Check if NACL and Security Group allow inbound traffic on port 8002

Comment: 1, 2, & 3 are all okay; 4. The Security Group does allow traffic on TCP 8002; what is NACL and where do I check it?

Comment: NACL - Network Access Control List. If you have created a new VPC, AWS will create a default NACL by allowing both inbound and outbound traffic unless you edit it. So it couldn't be the issue in your case.

Comment: Could you share your instance's security group configurations?

Comment: Here's a screenshot of the security group config: [link](http://imgur.com/a/n0kfv)

Comment: Going through the troubleshooting document, I did find the NACL, and it does allow all traffic.

Comment: Well, security group config looks okay to me. (Side-note: You should probably not open SSH port to Everyone as it is security threat)

Answer (score 0):

As per the document, Amazon states:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/using-instance-addressing.html#concepts-private-addresses

> We resolve an external DNS hostname to the public IP address of the
>   instance outside the network of the instance, and to the private IPv4
>   address of the instance from within the network of the instance

So may be it's not able to resolve the public IP if you are hitting it from localhost.